# How to connect raspberry pi zero v1.3 with arduino over bluetooth (HC-06)

Tags: bluetooth, pi-zero, arduino

I have raspberry pi zero v1.3 which have no build in bluetooth, i want to use hc-06 bluetooth module with raspberry pi and arduino for serial communication, just for receiving data from arduino to raspberry pi over bluetooth using hc-06 on both sides. please guide me.

Answer (score 3):

Connect the HC-06 to the serial PINs on the Raspberry Pi:

```
Raspberry Pi - HC-06
         Tx  -  Rx
         Rx  -  Tx
```

You can read more details here : https://steemit.com/technology/@techvlogs/bluetooth-module-hc-06-on-raspberry-pi

And for the Arduino do the same as for Raspberry Pi, just replace "Raspberry Pi" with Arduino.

And to pair two HC-0(5 or 6) is done with AT commands and in short:

- Choose witch is MASTER and the other become SLAVE.
- Set PIN
- Note hardware address for both MASTER and SLAVE.

Follow the instruction here for all steps and detailed explanation:
https://alselectro.wordpress.com/2014/10/21/bluetooth-hc05-how-to-pair-two-modules/

And next time do a search on Internet before asking ;-)